# Android Application with android-support-v4.jar added to lib facing error while trying to sign in using proguard in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: android, intellij-idea, proguard

I am trying to sign my application. Without checking the proguard the Sign in process goes fine. But if I am using the proguard I am getting the following stack trace. I have tried adding:

```
-dontwarn CompatHoneycomb -keep class android.support.v4. { *; }
-dontwarn **CompatCreatorHoneycombMR2
-dontwarn **ActivityCompatHoneycomb
-dontwarn **MenuCompatHoneycomb
```

lines to progaurd.cfg and also updating the progaurd.cfg by downloading the new version and copy pasting the jars and also have checked for any spaces in project location. None of them seems to work.

*The applications min sdk version is 9. I am looking to load the application onto galaxy tab running android 3.2(Just thought these details might be needed)*

```
**Error:Warning: android.support.v4.os.ParcelableCompatCreatorHoneycombMR2: can't find superclass or interface android.os.Parcelable$ClassLoaderCreator

Error:Warning: android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompatIcs$1: can't find superclass or interface android.view.View$AccessibilityDelegate

Error:Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManagerCompatIcs$1: can't find superclass or interface android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager$AccessibilityStateChangeListener

Error:Warning: android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompatIcs: can't find referenced method 'boolean getCanRetrieveWindowContent()' in class android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfo

Error:Warning: android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompatIcs: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.String getDescription()' in class android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfo

Error:Warning: android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompatIcs: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.String getId()' in class android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfo

Error:Warning: android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompatIcs: can't find referenced method 'android.content.pm.ResolveInfo getResolveInfo()' in class android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfo

Error:Warning: android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompatIcs: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.String getSettingsActivityName()' in class android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfo

Error:Warning: android.support.v4.os.ParcelableCompatCreatorHoneycombMR2: can't find referenced class android.os.Parcelable$ClassLoaderCreator

Error:Warning: android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.view.View$AccessibilityDelegate

Error:Warning: android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo

Error:Warning: android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompatIcs$1: can't find referenced class android.view.View$AccessibilityDelegate

Error:Warning: android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompatIcs$1: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo

Error:Warning: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatICS: can't find referenced method 'boolean canScrollHorizontally(int)' in class android.view.View

Error:Warning: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatICS: can't find referenced method 'boolean canScrollVertically(int)' in class android.view.View

Error:Warning: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatICS: can't find referenced class android.view.View$AccessibilityDelegate

Error:Warning: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatICS: can't find referenced method 'void setAccessibilityDelegate(android.view.View$AccessibilityDelegate)' in class android.view.View

Error:Warning: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatICS: can't find referenced method 'void onPopulateAccessibilityEvent(android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent)' in class android.view.View

Error:Warning: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatICS: can't find referenced method 'void onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent)' in class android.view.View

Error:Warning: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatICS: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo

Error:Warning: android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatICS: can't find referenced method 'void onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo)' in class android.view.View

Error:Warning: android.support.v4.view.ViewGroupCompatIcs: can't find referenced method 'boolean onRequestSendAccessibilityEvent(android.view.View,android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent)' in class android.view.ViewGroup

Error:Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEventCompatIcs: can't find referenced method 'int getRecordCount()' in class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent

Error:Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEventCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord

Error:Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEventCompatIcs: can't find referenced method 'void appendRecord(android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord)' in class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent

Error:Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEventCompatIcs: can't find referenced method 'android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord getRecord(int)' in class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent

Error:Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManagerCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager$AccessibilityStateChangeListener

Error:Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManagerCompatIcs: can't find referenced method 'boolean addAccessibilityStateChangeListener(android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager$AccessibilityStateChangeListener)' in class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager
Error:Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManagerCompatIcs: can't find referenced method 'boolean removeAccessibilityStateChangeListener(android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager$AccessibilityStateChangeListener)' in class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager

Error:Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManagerCompatIcs: can't find referenced method 'java.util.List getEnabledAccessibilityServiceList(int)' in class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager

Error:Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManagerCompatIcs: can't find referenced method 'java.util.List getInstalledAccessibilityServiceList()' in class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager

Error:Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManagerCompatIcs: can't find referenced method 'boolean isTouchExplorationEnabled()' in class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager

Error:Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManagerCompatIcs$1: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager$AccessibilityStateChangeListener

Error:Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo

Error:Warning: android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord

Error:Warning: android.support.v4.widget.EdgeEffectCompatIcs: can't find referenced class android.widget.EdgeEffect

Error:Warning: there were 124 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.

Error:         You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').

Error:Warning: there were 20 unresolved references to program class members.

Error:         Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.

Error:         You may need to recompile them and try again.

Error:         Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 

Error:         '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.

Error:java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.

Error:  at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)

Error:  at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)

Error:  at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)

Error:  at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)**
```

Comment: Any luck on this?  I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I found the a hack for the problem i have added a command in progaurd.cfg and vola it works fine now

-dontwarn android.support.v4.**

I am not sure if its the rite way to because i understand that i am just suppressing the warnings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the a hack for the problem i have added a command in progaurd.cfg and vola it works fine now

```
-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
```

I am not sure if its the right way, because as i understand, i am just suppressing the warnings.

Answer (score 9):

add this cfg line:
-dontwarn android.support.**
you can see it in you sdk like:
android-sdks/tools/proguard/docs/index.html
which say :
If you're using the Android Compatibility library, you should add the following line, to let ProGuard know it's ok that the library references some classes that are not available in all versions of the API:

```
-dontwarn android.support.**
```

Comment: In case anyone else is wondering, the file that I had to add this line to was proguard-project.txt

Answer (score 2):

-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
 Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

While the min SDK level is 9 you can target higher SDK levels, if you haven't tried this I'd suggest targeting 14, this solves a very similar problekm for me.

Comment: If u do that u cannot install the app on phones whose SDK which are less than 3.3

Comment: Not so, you can set your target and min SDKs to be different, the app will install on phones down to API level 9 (2.3) if you keep that as the min level. It just means that when the APK is built it will use the latest tools. You do have to be careful yourself that you don't add any API calls that are greater than 9, I think you can use Lint to check on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you download the last version of Android tools, you should place the support library on the /libs folder.

Maybe this is your problem.