# How to solve errors - Proguard - Android

Tags: android, proguard

I have a problem with Proguard (Eclipse for Windows), When I build my app for virtual device, it works perfect (no errors), but when I try to export it crushes and report a long list of errors, can anyone help me to solve it?

List of problems: http://notepad.cc/share/lWMVb3xmZE

proguard.cfg file: http://notepad.cc/share/chV9ADV23B

Android 2.2 (SDK 8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your proguard.cfg file in your project

```
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
}

**Edit:**

-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; } 
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.* { *; }
```

**Edit:**

See this: [Android Application with android-support-v4.jar added to lib facing error while trying to sign in using progaurd in IntelliJ Idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949634/android-application-with-android-support-v4-jar-added-to-lib-facing-error-while)

Comment: The same errors, this is my proguard.cfg file: http://notepad.cc/share/chV9ADV23B Any idea?

Comment: I didn't see that you were using the android compatibility library v4 the first time I saw it. Add this and let me know if it works:        -keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }

Comment: Similar errors, I've updated my proguard.cfg file: http://notepad.cc/share/chV9ADV23B and the errors list: http://notepad.cc/share/lWMVb3xmZE it still not works, any idea?

Comment: Looks like you did not add both lines I gave you. They look similar and you probably omitted one for that reason. Look closer. One is for the classes and the other is for interfaces. You need both. Also, please update your original question with all the 3rd party libraries and android compatibility libraries that you have added. And add "-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers" (without quotes) to the top of the file.

Comment: Similar errors (think so), I've updated both files again - proguard.cfg file: notepad.cc/share/chV9ADV23B and the errors list: notepad.cc/share/lWMVb3xmZE it still not works, I also added both lines you gave me (almost at bottom: -keep class android.support.v4.app.* { *; }  -keep interface android.support.v4.app.* { *; } I make a little change on one asterisk else it crush... more :P if I put this "app.*** { ; }" instead this "app.* { *; }" ) and also the new line, like you said at the top, any idea?

Comment: At this point, I would recommend that you do this: android update project -p "the path of your project" . "android" will be found under your android sdk folder/tools/..this will generate the necessary proguard config files.

Comment: Still no works, it created a buil.xml file and updated a local.properties file, no other changes, I've been tried to export application, and it crushed again, exactly the same errors, any other idea?

Comment: Still the same errors? Please update your original question with the libraries that you are using, both 3rd party and android add extras.

Comment: What is in your /libs folder? Do you have any other library project references in your project? Please list those as well. What you have listed right now is not helpful.

Comment: iside of my 'libs' folder: 'android-support-v4.jar' I'm not use external libraries.

Comment: See the last Edit I made to this answer.

Comment: Thanks it works I've added this lines to proguard.cfg file: -dontwarn android.support.v4.** -dontwarn android.support.** and the other you said, I've updated the file if someone needs it as I did, thanks again  :) http://notepad.cc/share/chV9ADV23B