# AccesibilityNodeInfo not found after importing project

Tags: java, android

I've imported an existing eclipse project, but it can't find certain classes.

`import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo;`

is shown as an error. Why is this happening?

Obviously this is a part of the default android support directory (android.support.v4.blablah)

HELP PLEASE!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Application with android-support-v4.jar added to lib facing error while trying to sign in using progaurd in IntelliJ Idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949634/android-application-with-android-support-v4-jar-added-to-lib-facing-error-while)

Comment: @user3131565 if my answer is helpful then you can select my answer

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting may be because your program not able to find required class i.e `android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo;` so you have to download the jar containing this class and then set your classpath